# randomForest using caret : shows incorrect mtry value

Tags: r-caret

I am trying randomForest using the 'caret' package. 
When I run the basic command without providing any controls, it shows that caret used **mtry=5** in the final model. ie, it **used 5 predictors**.
However, my data has 4 predictors. Can anyone explain why it shows mtry=5?
Here is my code:

> ```
>   library(caret)
>   data(iris)
>   set.seed(100)
>   model.rf = train(Petal.Length~., data=iris, method="rf")
> ```

```
   print(model.rf$finalModel)

   Call:
   randomForest(x = x, y = y, mtry = param$mtry) 
           Type of random forest: regression
                 Number of trees: 500
   No. of variables tried at each split: 5

      Mean of squared residuals: 0.06799251
                % Var explained: 97.8
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not specify a grid search, then the model info for method = "rf" will by default use `var_seq(p = ncol(x))` where in this case x is the dataset iris. If you use `var_seq(ncol(iris))` it will return 2 3 and 5. These values will be used in the default grid search for the mtry paramater. This returns 3 rf models and the one with the lowest rmse will be chosen as the final model. You can see this by just typing model.rf.

The reason you see 5 has to do with your seed. If you set the seed to 99 the chosen model will have an mtry of 3.

Of course just because the mtry is 5 does not mean that there suddenly is an extra variable to be chosen. It will just take all the variables available.

Answer (score 0):

@phiver, Thank you for explaining var_seq. I am afraid it does not provide the full answer to my question. 
 I found out that the following function provides the answer.

```
predictors(model.rf) 
#[1] "Sepal.Length"      "Sepal.Width"       "Petal.Width"      
#[4] "Speciesversicolor" "Speciesvirginica"
```

We see that caret replaces the categorical predictor 'Species' with 2 **dummy** variables. This is why we see 5 predictors, though we have 4 actual predictors for predicting Sepal.Length.  (I assume that you are familiar with iris data, hence I am not giving the details of its data structure.).

Comment: The 5 predictors are indeed, as you write, coming from creating dummy vars. But having 5 predictors, is no reason for mtry = 5. That has to do with the grid search. Adjust your code with set.seed(99) and you will see that mtry will be 3

Comment: @Phiver, Perhaps I was not clear in my description. Yes, caret tried mtry= (2, 3, 5)  and picked the best one. There is no question about it. My question was 'Where did it find the 5th predictor?' The answer is 'from the dummy variables' created by caret.

Answer (score -2):

I think that the mtry value means the number of forests used in you model.